# Syntax error while trying to install a library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to run the Python OpenCV library on my computer. I installed Python 3.11 from the website. However, all methods found on other forums result in syntax errors when I try to install the library.

I tried running `pip install opencv-python` at the IDLE prompt.

I expected it installed OpenCV and `pip` to be included with every Python downloads. However, when I ran that command, I got a syntax error.

> [image: screenshot]

This implies `pip` may not be working. I tried bootlegging it, and manually installing `pip` as per guides on Stack Overflow, but they do not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it feels like it should not be this difficult to install a library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should type `pip install opencv-python` in a terminal/shell window.

You are trying to run it inside IDLE, which accepts Python code, not Shell commands.

Comment: py -m pip install pip seems to have got me there, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From the image that you've shared, it seems that you're trying to run pip from (IDLE) ie: inside the python interpreter. That is why it is giving an error. The python interpreter is used to run python code and that is why it is giving a syntax error because 'pip' is not a python command. 'pip' is a separate utility that is used to install python packages.

So I would recommend you to try again by running the same command
`pip install opencv-python` in a separate terminal window in mac or linux or cmd/powershell for windows.

Also if that doesn't work, try upgrading your pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`